# ActiveModel::Serializer でモデル名を省略する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

既存のRailsプロジェクトのAPIを作りたく下記のようなSerializerを作りました。

```
class Api::V1::BaseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  def created_at
    object.created_at.in_time_zone.iso8601 if object.created_at
  end

  def updated_at
    object.updated_at.in_time_zone.iso8601 if object.created_at
  end
end

class Api::V1::UserSerializer < Api::V1::BaseSerializer
  attributes :id, :email, :created_at, :updated_at
end
```

これで設定したURLにアクセスすると以下の様な値を返してくれるようにはなりました。

```
{"user":{"id":1,"email":"foo@example.com","created_at":"2015-01-23T19:23:14+09:00","updated_at":"2016-02-27T02:24:10+09:00"}}
```

できればこの `"user"`部分を省き

```
{"id":1,"email":"foo@example.com","created_at":"2015-01-23T19:23:14+09:00","updated_at":"2016-02-27T02:24:10+09:00"}
```

を返したいのですがどうすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

デフォルトのノードを表示させないためには`root: false`を指定する必要がありました。
このような感じで。

```
format.json { render json: @user, root: false }
```

[英語版の該当記事](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350859/make-root-node-in-active-model-serializer)